# AWS RDS and Multiple Database Installation

Tags: database, multi-sites

Does anyone have experience with setting up a Drupal Multi-Site with multiple Databases onto one RDS instance in AWS?

I was looking into this link below but I was not familiar with the exact formatting: https://www.drupal.org/node/18429

Here is my format:

```
$databases = array (
'default' =>  // main drupal db starts from here
array (
'default' => 
array (
  'database' => 'PubDB',
  'username' => 'PubUser',
  'password' => 'PASSWORD',
  'host' => 'pubtest.amazonaws.com',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
),
),'careers' =>  // additional database starts here
array (
'default' => 
array (
  'database' => 'careers', // additional database name
  'username' => 'PubUser', // additional database username
  'password' => 'PASSWORD', // additional database password
  'host' => 'pubtest.amazonaws.com',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'sql', //the file is in sql format
  'prefix' => '',
)
),
);
```

And on my database.inc file I have:

```
function db_set_active($key = 'careers') {
return Database::setActiveConnection($key);
}
db_set_active();
```

Comment: I would like to bump this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. :)

Here are the steps I took on a RDS under a VPC:

1. Created each Database individually on MySQL and then dumped each DB.

To log into your RDS MySQL:

```
mysql -h RDSEndPoint.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u MasterUser -p
```

To dump

```
mysql -u MasterUser -p -h RDSEndPoint.rds.amazonaws.com DB_Name_on_MySQL < /my/file/location/SQL_FILE.sql (You might need to change the .sql to .mysql)
```

2. Once you have your DB's set up and ready to go, change your /var/www/html/MySiteFolder/sites/default/settings.php file

To

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'DB_Name_on_MySQL',
      'username' => 'MasterUser',
      'password' => 'PASSWORD',
      'host' => 'RDSEndPoint.rds.amazonaws.com',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

3. You might receive this error (https://www.drupal.org/node/2394349):

   Command updatedb needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.       [error]

   The drush command 'updatedb' could not be executed.                  [error]

   A Drupal installation directory could not be found                   [error]

You can run the following two commands on where each of your sites index.php file is located:

```
drush dl rules 
drush updatedb
```

You should be able to see your site now! If I'm missing something I would be glad to add it for future reference.